# how can i bind function one time once i click submit button? for jquery ajax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

i use django make a website .
 i want to let people create group in my website .so i use html form to let them fill in the info and upload an image as the group logo.
as i want to let people preview the logo,so i use ajax upload the picture file first.i add 2 buttons in the page,button1 is for upload picture file in ajax way,button2 is for post the whole form to the server .for the ajax upload picture ,i use this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
ok here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.form.min.js"></script> 

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>




<form id="test" action="/accounts/signup/" method="post">
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" />
<input type="file" name="file" id ="file" /> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn_gray_light" id="tnpicsubmit"><span >submitpicture</span></a>

<a href="javascript:;" class="btn_celadon_large signup"><span>confirm</span></a>
</form>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){

$("#tnpicsubmit").click(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(){
       var options={
            url:"/article/nodetpic/",
            type:"POST",
            datatype:"json",


        };

        $("#form").ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    }).submit();

});


$(".signup").click(function(){
    $("#test").submit()

});
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this code works,but not well.
because ,the first time i choose one picture,and click the button  id #tnpicsubmit,yes the picture uploaded to my host,i through every thing is ok .then i test the 2nd time,and this time ,the same picture file ,upload 2 times,i find 2 same pictures in the host ,and i test 3rd time ,same picture upload 3 times.
now i know the problem where is .i think the problem is ,every time i click the button id #tnpicsubmit,it add the same function to the form submit event,that is why every time i get +1 times picture uploaded.

how to solve this problem ?i mean,just one click ,upload one picture one time for ajax file upload.

Comment: Reason there is no validation?

Comment: you can try my code ,then you will know my problem .the problem is ,i add a form submit addtion handle to a certain button click event.how every .my code will add +1 time every time the button clicked .that is not i want.

Comment: My point was why don't you validate it to see if it was clicked and has the same previous data...validation.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand your question, try using `one()`:

```
$("#form").one('submit', function(){...});
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the callback for the submit event to be called for every submit event, but doesn't want to bind the submit handler over and over

Comment: hi.i just want the form has the submit handle to ajax one time.the problem is ,use my way ,every time i click the button #tnpicsubmit,it will add +1 time same submit handle to the form ,then the same picture upload +1 times .you can try my code ,then you will understand

Comment: @zzlettle you should provide a jsfiddle if you want me to test it, otherwise, i won't... That's said, so this answer is not what you are looking for?!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the submit handler inside the click event and then calling it. It is adding another handler every time you click the button. Solve the issue by moving the submit handler outside the click event.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(){
       var options={
            url:"/article/nodetpic/",
            type:"POST",
            datatype:"json",


        };

        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });


$("#tnpicsubmit").click(function(){
    $("#form").submit();
});


$(".signup").click(function(){
    $("#test").submit()

});
})

</script>
```

I don't see #tnpicsubmit in the html. But it could be an  so you can use less JavaScript.